# pass jQuery(this) in ajax.load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a parameter to `ajax.load()`. I want to pass `this` from parent function to `ajax.load()`. I want to use this inside it

Here is my code:

```
ajax.done(function(msg) {
    jQuery(this).children('p').append(msg); 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a variable which will hold the desired value in the closure :

```
var $this = $(this);
ajax.done(function(msg) {
    $this.children('p').append(msg); 
});
```

Comment: Nice job.  Also note that "var $this" can be "var mthis", or "var that", or "var whatever", enjoy!